# Public guest user for PostgreSQL?

Tags: databases, rest, account-security, opensource, postgresql

I manage an open-source software project that relies on data that I am happy to share with the public. The software is hosted on github.com, but the dataset is too large to host there. It is easiest to keep the dataset in the form of a relational database, currently stored on a PostgreSQL server in my university lab. I'm assuming it would be considered bad practice to create a read-only "guest" user account on my PostgreSQL server and publish the credentials along with the software. Is that true? If so, why? And can you suggest a secure way to share a relational database with the public?

My alternative is probably to setup an HTTP server that either delivers standardized results from particular RESTful endpoints, or accepts ad hoc queries for the database (I assume the latter is also a bad idea). But I'd like to get a good idea of why I should do that before going down that path.

Comment: It's generally considered a Bad Idea(tm) to directly expose your datastore and instead shift it to something like APIs as you suggested. However, I'm not entirely sure what you are looking to solve here. Are you looking for design/architecture help?

Comment: Mostly I'm looking for comments on how bad an idea it would be to create a read-only guest account on my database server and offer that to the public, and why. I assume the main concern would be privilege escalation and/or that I don't lock it down enough or someone finds an exploit and gets write access and messes with my database. Secondary to that, I'd like to hear if there are some "best practices" or easy ways to provide public access to a datastore. Otherwise, I'll go ahead with the HTTP API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already mentioned some of the problems:

- misconfiguration is easy,
- privilege escalation bugs could put you at risk,
- offering raw, more or less uncontrolled access to the data can lead to DOS situations.

But there are some additional problems with your idea:

This means that your university will be bound to offer the service as long as the product is in use by anyone. Continuity is a problem; if one of your users decides to clone the whole database over that connection, it might become unresponsive for others. Additionally, there might be people that want that software to run without an internet connection.

While an http-API is the way to go to let people use your database relatively safely in general, in this particular case, the best way - from my point of view - would be to use good compression on a database dump and host that file for download on your university server if it’s too big for github.

This way, you do not needlessly introduce a single point of failure for the application to work and put yourself to less risk, let alone spare yourself some tedious, possibly vulnerability-introducing work.

Comment: Yeah, and PostgreSQL doesn't offer strong QoS features.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I had already started thinking I should move to a model where I provide an HTTP API, where my software can send the parameters for its queries, and then the server can run some standard queries and send back a collection of CSV files with the requested data. But I'll have to think about the other issues you raised - DOS and autonomy for software users.